# Gradle application plugin stuck at 96% when runs app?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I'm using the Gradle application plugin to run my Java service, and when I do `./gradlew myservice:run`, it runs the service successfully and shows the console output, but the Gradle process gets stuck at 96%:

`Building 96% > :myservice:run`

Is this the way the application plugin is supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

It will be 'stuck' here until you quit your application. `myservice:run` is a task that runs your application and waits until it finishes. You see 96% because that's an estimation of build progress based on tasks in a task graph that has to be executed.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to run it asynchronously without doing something ghetto like an 'exec' call?

Comment: 1. Run Java on your own. `gradle --debug myapp:run` will tell you what args you need to pass. 2. Start another Gradle build without worrying about this. If the buildscript(s) is not changed it should run.